# sequelize ORM asynchronous method calls

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

How can I call methods asynchronously in sequelize ORM? (because I have to use returned value inside other methods).

user.dao.js:

```
var User = require('./user.model');

class UserDao {
constructor() {}

insert(user) {
    var pk;
    User.sync({ force: false }).then(() => {
        User.create(user).then(function(user) {
            console.log('Entry successful from dao: ' + 
    JSON.stringify(user));
            //return generated pk
            pk = user.id;
            console.log('ID: ' + pk);
        });
    });
    return pk;
}
```

user.test.js:

```
class UserDaoTest {
constructor() {
    this.userDao = new UserDao();
    this.compare = new UtilsObject();
}

/*
    all CRUD method calls
*/
testAll() {
    this.testInsert();
    this.testUpdate();
    //this.testDelete();
    //this.testRead();
    //this.compare();
}

/*
    insert method
*/
testInsert() {
    // composite form
    var user = {
        name: 'nisha',
        email: 'nisha@gmail.com',
        phoneNo: 8978,
        picUrl: 'nisha',
        description: 'SI',
        status: 'active',
        waitingTime: 10,
        rating: 7
    };

    /*
        calling insert user with above data
    */
    var pk = this.userDao.insert(user);
    console.log('pk value: ' + pk);
    //var obj1 = this.userDao.readById(pk);
    console.log('obj1 value: ' + user);
    //this.testReadById(obj1);
}

testReadById(obj1) {
    var obj2 = this.userDao.readById(obj1);
    this.compare.compare(obj1, obj2);
    this.testDelete(obj1);
}
}

export default UserDaoTest;
```

Here in user.test.js, in testInsert() method want to get the value of pk which is returned from insert() method of user.dao.js, but right now I am getting pk value as undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Use a promise chain.
Suppose you need to get an entry for a particular user & do some operations on it.

```
Model.User.findById(someId)
.then((user) => {
   // Do something with user.
})
```

You shouldn't be calling methods synchronously, NodeJs is not designed this way. It works with callbacks or promises.

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't work because it is async code.

Watch the famous [Youtube video about the event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=25s)

But in short, if you will run the following example, which is like your code but without your logic:

```
var User = require('./user.model');

class UserDao {
constructor() {}

insert(user) {
    var pk; 
    console.log('1');
    User.sync({ force: false }).then(() => {
        pk = 123;
        console.log('3'); 
    });
    console.log('2');
    return pk; 
}
```

The variable `pk` will be `undefined` and your console will look like this:

```
1
2
3
```

If you want it to work, you should "wait" for the async functions like this:

```
var User = require('./user.model');

class UserDao {
    constructor() {}

    // @return Promise
    insert(user) {
         return User.sync({ force: false }).then(() => {
             return User.create(user)
         }).then((user) => {
             console.log('Entry successful from dao: ' + JSON.stringify(user));
             return user.id
         })
    }
```

And when you use it:

```
class UserDaoTest {
    constructor() {
        this.userDao = new UserDao();
        this.compare = new UtilsObject();
    }

    /*
        all CRUD method calls
    */
    testAll() {
        // if testInsert and testUpdate can run simultaneously you can keep it like this. 
        // Otherwise, use Promise.then as well
        this.testInsert();
        this.testUpdate(); 
    }

    /*
        insert method
    */

    testInsert() {
        var user = {
            // ...
        };

        /*
            calling insert user with above data
        */
        this.userDao.insert(user).then((userId) => {
            // YOUR COMPARE CODE
        }).then(done); // Where done is a function to let you test framework that you async code is done
    }
}

export default UserDaoTest;
```

Another way of doing that is using the new `async` and `await`. That way you will get a code which is more readable and maintainable.

You can read more [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/)